# Create many objects. Django REST framework

Tags: django, python-2.7, rest, django-rest-framework

I wish create same objects, which will be differ only ForeignKeyField.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
```

I created serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serialiser.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta():
          model = User
          fields = ('id',)

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     recipients = UserSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta():
         fields = (text,)
```

I get json like this: `{"text":"Text", "recipients" : [{"id": 3}, {"id": 1}, {"id":2}]}`.

And I want create for each user (by "id") new object MyModel. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `.create()` method of `MyModelSerializer`.

At the end it should be something like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    if 'recipients' in validated_data:
        recipients_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
    else:
        recipients_data = []

    for recipient_data in recipients_data:
        created_my_model = MyModel.objects.create(recipient=User.objects.get(id=recipient_data['id']),
                                                  text=validated_data['text'])

    return something # here you need to decide what to return
```

I wouldn't request User's object in the loop though. But you see the idea.

Comment: that's good, but I can't return list of MyModel objects, and recipients is empty OrderedDict

Comment: As for what to return, it depends on what you need. By default I would return an object similar to the one you received (but maybe with serialized Users in it, instead of list of IDs). If you don't need any created data in the return you can return an empty dict. Response code should be 201, which will indicate that creation was successful.